# how to null out a insert statement?

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

I am doing a SQLi-Quiz. Below is the orignal statement.

```
insert into users(name,pass) values('bob', [injection point here])
```

The statement is heavily filterd because the website which supplys the quiz doesn't want someone breaks the whole database. I can't find any way to get this one done so I search a hint on the forum of the quiz. From the search results I know that the only way to make this quiz done is, someone must nullify the whole orginal query. It means that the value "bob" must be nullified too.

As I know I can't influence the query before the injection point. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Why do you think the `bob` value must be nullified and what would be the result of doing so?

Comment: Good question. Honestly, I have no ideas either. I find this quiz is very hard to understand. If you have interest figure out the answer yourself. Can you give me you e-mail address? I will send you the address of the quiz.

Comment: Why don’t you post the address here?

Comment: http://www.enigmagroup.org/missions/basics/sql/4/   You must get an account to access it.

Comment: What is the goal of this mission?

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a subquery in place of the injection point. For starters in case of mysql

1. Select concat(version(),user(),database())
2. Select grantee from information_schema.USER_PRIVILEGES

Also check out for sql-map tool